# how to configure apache 2.4.10 to run python code in it

Tags: python, apache

The sites-enabled ,000-default.conf file is changed for apache 2.4.10 so I am not able to configure apache due to this, is there any one who can give a step by step description in how to configure?

This is my 000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
```

> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

```
    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

> vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

where am I supposed to change the setting?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19578091/4014959) may be helpful.

Comment: I am running on ubuntu mate,the configeration of apache is different from the before versions, thats why having difficulty, and @PM2Ring My sites-availabe doesnt have my_cgi_dir, it only has 000-default.conf , do you have any solution for this?